# Sql select from multiple tables where in doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a website where there are multiple pages and each page has a table in the database and when you follow pages you like. I want posts from the pages you follow to show up in your newsfeed. This will need to select from multiple tables. This is what i tried so far:

```
Select page-id, id, content
from page1, page2, page3, page4
where page-id in(select p_id from follows where p_username = '$me')
```

But I get this error:

```
Column 'page-id' in field list is ambiguous
```

Help?

Comment: try 'page-id' or [page-id]

Comment: So what `page-id` do you expect?

Comment: @u_mulder i test page-id from both tables, if its found as p_id in table follows

Comment: Do you think mysql engine could guess it?

Comment: @u_mulder i dont want to guess it. I want to select from both tables. Both not either one. BOTH

Comment: Do I want to know why you have multiple tables named `page1`, `page2` and so on? That seems like a really problematic schema.

Comment: I'm telling not about you, I'm telling about mysql engine. How does it know what fields do you want exactly if fields with such names are more then one, huh?

Comment: @tadman can you please be polite?

Comment: @tadman because each page has its own table. There are actually 4 pages only and each page has content field in each table. This field is what shows in the newsfeed

Comment: I'm being as polite as I can be. This schema is trouble because relational databases are intended to work by relating record data, the table name should be irrelevant. You should have a `page` column in a single table that describes whatever your independent page tables have in them currently. This will make your life *considerably* easier. The reason for my concern is sometimes quirky situations like this arise because they're product of some other, even quirkier thing.

Comment: So in general, don't violate the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) unless you have a very compelling reason. Standard [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) practices work very well under the majority of circumstances, and when they break down you're usually dealing with some exceptionally complex data, hopefully a rare thing for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Column 'page-id' in field list is ambiguous
```

That means that "page-id" find it in more than one table, you must use the table name to identify or alias

```
Select a.page-id, id, content
from page1 a, page2 b, page3 c, page4 d
where a.page-id in(select p_id from follows where p_username = '$me')
```

but I do not think that's what you want with that query, you have to explain more.

EDIT, reading the scaisEdge's answer

If you want get all tables as one, you need UNION

```
 (SELECT page-id, id, content
  FROM page1
  WHERE page-id in(SELECT p_id FROM follows WHERE p_username = '$me'))
UNION
 (SELECT page-id, id, content
  FROM page2
  WHERE page-id in(SELECT p_id FROM follows WHERE p_username = '$me'))
UNION
 (SELECT ...) ...
```

But, you know the number of pages? you can make the query with php 
dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Yuo must assign the table name to the column because there are  more tables with the same column name eg:

```
  "Select page1.page-id, page2.page-id, id,content 
  from  page1,page2,page3,page4 
  where page1.page-id in(select p_id from follows where p_username='$me')"
```

or if you need select the same column for all the tables you can use union

```
  "Select page-id,  id, content 
  from  page1
  where page-id in(select p_id from follows where p_username='$me')
  union 
  Select page-id,  id, content 
  from  page2
  where page-id in(select p_id from follows where p_username='$me')
  union 
  Select page-id,  id, content 
  from  page3
  where page-id in(select p_id from follows where p_username='$me')
  union
  Select page-id,  id, content 
  from  page4
  where page-id in(select p_id from follows where p_username='$me')
```

"

Comment: I want to select column page-id from both tables

Comment: I have update the answer  .. for select both the columns

Comment: Still doesnt work as i want. I want it to treat all tables as one table. understand me?

Comment: I have update the answer .. with union .. .. you understand me? what mean?

Answer (score 1):

#### Why your query doesn't do what you want it to do

The `JOIN` produces four `page-id` columns, four `id` columns, four `content` columns. `SELECT` cannot automatically figure our which one you want. Use `LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE` (Solution 1) or four different queries with `UNION` (Solution 2). Consider revising your table architecture (Suggestions).

#### Solution 1

This solution uses a `LEFT JOIN` with `follows` on the left side of the join. That means that every row in the result set will be based on one row from `follows`. The columns from the other tables will be selected too, but they will be null if there is no match. The `COALESCE` function selects the first non-null value. This solution assumes that `page-id` is unique across the tables and that `id` and `content` are non-null when `page-id` is not null.

```
SELECT COALESCE(p1.`page-id`, p2.`page-id`, p3.`page-id`, p4.`page-id`) `page-id`
     , COALESCE(p1.id, p2.id, p3.id, p4.id) id
     , COALESCE(p1.content, p2.content, p3.content, p4.content) content
  FROM (((  follows f LEFT JOIN page1 p1 ON f.p_id = p1.`page-id`
         ) LEFT JOIN page2 p2 ON f.p_id = p2.`page-id`
        ) LEFT JOIN page3 p3 ON f.p_id = p3.`page-id`
       ) LEFT JOIN page4 p4 ON f.p_id = p4.`page-id`
 WHERE f.p_username = '$me'
;
```

#### Solution 2

Use separate `SELECT` statements with `UNION`. See solution by scaisEDGE (above). I use `JOIN` instead of `IN` with a subquery. In my experience, `IN`-with-subquery is less scalable and, depending on the database server and resources, can create performance problems.

```
SELECT `page-id`, id, content
  FROM page1 INNER JOIN follows ON `page-id` = p_id
 WHERE p_username = '$me'
UNION
SELECT `page-id`, id, content
  FROM page2 INNER JOIN follows ON `page-id` = p_id
 WHERE p_username = '$me'
UNION
SELECT `page-id`, id, content 
  FROM page3 INNER JOIN follows ON `page-id` = p_id
 WHERE p_username = '$me'
UNION
SELECT `page-id`, id, content
  FROM page4 INNER JOIN follows ON `page-id` = p_id
 WHERE p_username = '$me'
;
```

#### Suggestions

The table architecture seems questionable.

- How can you guarantee that `page-id` is unique?
- Why do you have a separate table for each page? It would seem to make more sense to have one `pages` table. Each row should identify the page. If you require separate physical files (e.g., for sharding) consider partitioning.
- The use of the hyphen in the name `page-id` may be hard for some validators and IDEs to interpret as a distinct column name. As a best practice, consider using only letters, numbers, and underscores in your column names. In my examples, I surround it with backticks to tell MySQL and IDE that it is an object name. I suggest `page_id` as a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS` instead of `IN` to have better performance when querying large data sets, for smaller datasets of few hundreds of rows `IN` and `EXISTS` does not make much of a difference

```
Select page1.page-id, page2.page-id,content 
  from  page1,page2,page3,page4 
  where exists (select p_id from follows where page1.page-id=follows.p_id and p_username='$me')
```

Comment: `EXISTS` is not necessarily better in all cases; in this case you've turned a normal subquery that would run once into a correlated subquery that will need to be executed for every row in the outer query.